# Changing Position Of an Element while Scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, parallax

I should need a cover page when my website first loaded. I split the cover page into two sections. On top section when the page is scrolled down logo should move to top-left corner and get smaller at the same time. The menu items which is under logo on cover page should slide upward and take its position on the page. So when scroll is completed, menu bar will be sticky on top. This What I want basically.

In order to achieve this i tried to manage scroll by jquery. I fixed cover page for amount of scroll to wait for complete of motions of logo and menu item. First I fix page till "scrollTop" reach "1000". In this scrolltime i need to move objects on cover page.

Here is HTML code

```
<div class="container-fluid position-fixed">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="presantation">
            <div id="show-top">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-offset-3 col-lg-6 col-md-offset-2 col-md-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
                        <div id="logo">
                            <img src="img/logo.png" class="logo-path img-responsive" name="start"/>
                        </div>              
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-8">
                        <div id="menu-list" name="description">
                            <ul class="menu-path">
                                <li>About Us</li>
                                <li>Services</li>
                                <li>portfolio</li>
                                <li>blog</li>
                                <li>contact</li>
                            </ul>

                        </div>              
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="show-bottom">
                <p>You´ve scrolled 0 pixels.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my jquery to keep page on window until scrolltop value reachs 1000

```
  $(window).on('scroll', function () { 
    //You've scrolled this much:
       $('p').text("You've scrolled " + $ (window).scrollTop() + " pixels");

       if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 1000) {
            $(".container-fluid").removeClass("position-fixed");
            if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 200) {
            $(".logo-path").css({"top":"-10px","left":"-10px"});                
            }
          }
        else {
            $(".container-fluid").addClass("position-fixed");
          } 
            });
```

I tried tried to add "top , left" values in css by jquery but it did not work out.

any help much appreciated

Comment: this is an exemple of an sticky header that sticks to the top of the page .
hope it helps :) [***The Link***](http://fiddle.jshell.net/3aX2C/8/)

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry i am not able add comment, so i am replying here.

1.
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 200) {
            $(".logo-path").css({"top":"-10px","left":"-10px"});
            }
This condition is not necessary i guess, because this will reach only when window scroll is above 1000.

1. I think you should give position:absolute  for logo path then top and left properly will set.
2. one of the Parent should have position :relative so logo will go to top and left.

Comment: Yes, I realised my mistake. So, i should make the position of logo absolute when parent is relative. But still confused about animation issue.

Comment: u can give animation to that logo when changing the property of logo.